# Grails pagination isn't working properly

Tags: grails, pagination

I'm a newbie to Grails and I've tried to use the pagination Tag found in the documentation to show specific data.

Pagination is showing on my page but it displays all my data on every page when I slide through them and I would like to display only 10 items per page from total sum.

This is my controller

```
class HomeController {

    def actions() {
       params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)

       def articleActionOpera = newSuggestedShoppingItemsService.getNewSuggestedShoppingItems()

       return [articles: articleActionOpera, actionTotal: articleActionOpera.size(), params:params]
    }
}
```

This is my service

```
class NewSuggestedShoppingItemsService {

   def operaOpusDbConnectorService

   def getNewSuggestedShoppingItems() {

      def returnRows = null
      def sqlInstance = operaOpusDbConnectorService.openOperaOpusConnection()

      try {
         def sqlQuery = "SELECT passW, ArtName, Descript FROM dbo.fnWS_Newarticles()"

         returnRows = sqlInstance.rows(sqlQuery)

         return returnRows
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {
         log.error("Fail, item are not shown.")
         throw new Exception (ex)
      }
   }
}
```

and my .gsp

...

```
<div id="paging">
   <g:paginate total="${actionTotal}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not passing any pagination parameters (max & offset) to your database query and hence getting all the records. So pass them to your query and this will work.

Second thing, you are passing the total count as the size of returned results (where value is correct but programmatically wrong) and max/offset to Grails pagination directive, i.e. why it is rendering proper pagination HTML snippet.

Example:

```
class HomeController {

    def actions(Integer max) {
       params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)

       List articleActionOpera = newSuggestedShoppingItemsService.getNewSuggestedShoppingItems()

       // You don't have to pass params in model, it is bydefault available in GSPs
       return [articles: articleActionOpera, actionTotal: articleActionOpera.totalCount]
    }
}
```

Service:

```
class NewSuggestedShoppingItemsService {

   List getNewSuggestedShoppingItems(Map params) {
      // Consider ShoppingItem is a domain class and params is containing max & 
      // offset parameters then it will return an instance of PagedResultList (List)
      // which will have a totalCount field

      List shoppingItems = ShoppingItem.createCriteria().list(params) {
           // Your criteria
           eq("status", "ACTIVE")
      }


      return shoppingItems
   }
}
```

Read more here http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Comment: Can you post some code example or explain how to do that for the thing's you mentioned?

Comment: Well, this is the most common thing in Grails. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work for me. this is the error that I'm getting             No such property: ShoppingItem for class: hr.svam.web.operaopus.NewSuggestedShoppingItemsService. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: ShoppingItem for class: hr.svam.web.operaopus.NewSuggestedShoppingItemsService

Comment: I've already mentioned in my example code that I'm using a sample domain. I was really not expecting that you will copy paste my example. Please ready about Grails domain classes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Damir use below instructions and you will easily achieve pagination in grails :

On view your code is ok : (No changes needed)

```
<div id="paging">
   <g:paginate total="${actionTotal}" />
</div>
```

In Controller :

```
class HomeController {

    def actions(Integer max) {
       params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
//change here
       List articleActionOpera = newSuggestedShoppingItemsService.getNewSuggestedShoppingItems(params)

       // You don't have to pass params in model, it is bydefault available in GSPs
       return [articles: articleActionOpera, actionTotal: articleActionOpera.totalCount,params:params]
    }
}
```

In service use create criteria :

```
class NewSuggestedShoppingItemsService {

   def operaOpusDbConnectorService

   def getNewSuggestedShoppingItems(def params) {

      def returnRows = null
   /*   def sqlInstance = operaOpusDbConnectorService.openOperaOpusConnection()

      try {
         def sqlQuery = "SELECT passW, ArtName, Descript FROM dbo.fnWS_Newarticles()"

         returnRows = sqlInstance.rows(sqlQuery)

         return returnRows
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {
         log.error("Fail, item are not shown.")
         throw new Exception (ex)
      }*/

returnRows=YourDomainName.createCriteria().list(params) {
 projections {
        property("passW")
        property("ArtName")
        property("Descript")
    }
}

   }
}
```

Note : must change YourDomainName == Name of Class which maps to table 
it will work properly.

Comment: So I have done what you said but now I'm geting a error of this tipe,           Class
org.hibernate.QueryException
Message
could not resolve property: passW of: hr.svam.web.operaopus.Ooarticle

Comment: property("passW") // Change passW with your domain property which maps to passW inn your table.
 property("ArtName")//Do the above thing for all these three property.
 property("Descript")
This 3 property are actually column names exist in your domain class to table. So replace them with domain class fields.

Comment: I have mapped data with the domain class as you said. but I'm still getting a error.                                                                                   Class
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException
Message
Cannot cast object 'false' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'java.util.List' what is the problem with this??

Comment: Send your complete code with your error, this is just  a type-casting error.